# Conditions of using webContentLink?

Tags: google-drive-api

Which kind of cookie is required to work with webContentLink? I noticed when I'm logged in to Gmail only, i get 403 error. When I open Google Drive too in on other tab and check some files, then my webContentLinks starts to work. Is this the way it should work or did I missed something? Once it was sufficient to be logged in only in Gmail...

(I have a very simple web application, that shows some links to files I shared with my friends in Google Drive. I don't want to use further authentication, but public is also not an option. It was very convenient to have accessible links when their Gmail is opened.)